# install :java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.221-alt4_2.6.18.0jpp8.x86_64.rpm Failed

Tags: java, json, linux, server, redhat-containers

i have issue on redhat 5.8 for installing java :java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.221-alt4_2.6.18.0jpp8.x86_64.rpm, but i face bellow error any one can give me comments

error:

```
rpm -ivh java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64.rpm 
warning: java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
error: Failed dependencies:
    ca-certificates is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    libpulse.so.0()(64bit) is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit) is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    rhino is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    tzdata-java is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9-2.3.4.1.el6_3.x86_64
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match the question.  The output is for an 1.7.0u9 rpm, but you are asking about 1.7.0u221.  Furthermore, the RPM in the output was built for RHEL 6 rather than RHEL 5.  (I don't know if this is the actual problem ... but it could be.)

Comment: You might find this relevant: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3012351.  It implies that the last version of Oracle Java 1.7 available for RHEL 5.x is `java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el5_11`